# Comparing textBox value to FLOAT sql

Tags: sql, vb.net

I'm having a search form where users enter a MAX and MIN values of budget to search between available projets with those criterias.

Whatever I put in those fields, it always shows same result (only for that field of search).

The field in database is called budget and is a float

Here is the value of the MAX (same as MIN)

```
Dim s = Convert.ToDouble(TxtBudgetMax.Text)
SearchMaxBud = " AND budget =< " & s & " "
```

And the query is just filled with

```
"SELECT * from Table where " & SearchMaxBud & ";"
```

I've tried making it a `Double`, a `Varchar` even, and nothing works with that. Any idea please ? Thanks

Comment: less than or equal to should be "<=" not "=<" and likewise greater than or equal to is ">="

Comment: The query doesn't return the projects with budget less or equal to .. and there where my problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the moment, the only problem i see with the query is the less than or equal to sign which should be `<=` and it currently is `=<` on this line:

```
SearchMaxBud = " AND budget =< " & s & " "
```

Other than that, use parameterized values to avoid SQL injections.

Here is the fix for your code:

```
Dim SearchMaxBud as string
Dim minval = Convert.ToDouble(TxtBudgetMin.Text)
SearchMaxBud += "budget >= @minVal"
Dim maxval = Convert.ToDouble(TxtBudgetMax.Text)
SearchMaxBud += " AND budget <= @maxVal"
Dim query = "SELECT * from Table where " & SearchMaxBud & ";"
```

And then fill in `@maxVal` and `@maxVal` with `SqlCommandObject.Parameters.AddWithValue()` method.

Comment: It was as simple as the placement of => and <= and another error of ANd & OR before that statement.